# RubyZip doesn't work well after updating zlib to v.1.2.12

Tags: ruby, zlib, rubyzip

I have updated zlib from 1.2.11 to 1.2.12. After this updating, RubyZip doesn't work well, The following code generates a zip file includeing a empty file named test.txt. In the environment using older version of zlib, the following code generates a zip file including a text file containing the text of "Hello World!"

Is there anyone who knows the way to get rid of this problem?

```
require 'zip'
require 'zlib'

Zip::OutputStream.open("test.zip", Zip::TraditionalEncrypter.new("password")) do |zip|
    zip.put_next_entry("test.txt")
    zip.print("Hello World!\n")
end
```

I'd like to know how to create a zip file with password using rubyzip with zlib v1.2.12 or later.

Comment: The easy answer is to revert to zlib 1.2.11. Please report the issue here: https://github.com/madler/zlib/issues

Comment: Thanks for advising. I have reported to github.https://github.com/madler/zlib/issues/623